# no wifi adapter found ubuntu 20.05 in hp pavilion dv5

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, 20.04, hp

I have this old hp pavilion dv5 in which I've been running ubuntu 20.04 (not dual boot) without issues until yesterday.

Suddenly, the wifi stopped working and in the wifi settings it said 'no wifi adapter found'. Since I had the same issue when I first installed ubuntu, I thought it was an easy fix. I connected via ethernet and tried to follow the steps detailed [here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/UBUNTU-No-WiFi-Adapter-Found-hp-pavilion-rtl8723de/m-p/6904094#M157980) in the last gray box of the accepted solution. I thought that was how I fixed the problem originally but now it doesn't work since the repo https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git no longer exists?

I have searched for other solutions but all seem to rely on said repo. Is there any other way to fix this problem?

Edit: Results from running lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net in the terminal:

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:144e]
   Kernel driver in use: r8169
   Kernel modules: r8169
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
   Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [103c:1483]
   Kernel driver in use: wl
   Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

Comment: Please edit the post to add results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

Comment: @Jeremy31 added. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) There is no Ubuntu 20.05.

Comment: Try `sudo apt update && sudo apt install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source` Then reboot

Comment: The correct command will be `sudo apt get purge bcmwl-kernel-source`. This adapter isn't properly supported by `wl`.